# Nyquist plot with one zero, four identical poles and one pole at origin

Tags: matlab, controls, nyquist

I am trying to draw the Nyquist plot of this transfer function

2 (s+1) / (s (s+10)^4)

This is my code:

```
NUM2 = [2 2];
DEN2 = [5 40 600 4000 10000 0];
FT2 = tf(NUM2,DEN2) 
fprintf ('\n Nyquist\n')
figure(2)
nyquist(FT2)
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is what I draw by hand

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The first entry in `DEN2` should be `1` not `5`.

Comment: Thanks! That is one of the problems.